# Is it correct to declare a variable whithout any statement?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

about variable declarations in node /javascript: var, let const, ...

I experimented in a node script

that if one declares a variable without any statement (`var`, `let const`, ...)

```
x = "my new var";
```

then `x` will have a global scope and will be visible from all the modules of the node project

question

Is it correct to declare a variable like that? or is it deprecated / contrary to the rules of language?

Comment: Which language is that? Please tag your question properly.

Comment: question edited ... I have indicated better that it is javascript / node

Comment: No, an assignment does not *declare* anything. It creates a property on the global object in sloppy mode, but there is no variable declared by this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It compiles fine, so it is not contrary to the rules of the language and is not deprecated as far as I know. It is considered bad practice, for the same reason global variables are considered bad practice in all languages. One example, especially with a generic name like `x`, is you might override it locally by mistake and get some unexpected results. There are plenty other of caveats.

It might be OK sometimes. One use case I can think of is if you want to use `pi` everywhere in your program, declaring it globally would make sense. Of course, it would be better to wrap it in a `constants` class, but for a single constant a class may be overkill, and I would define PI = 3.14 at the top of my program.

Answer (score 2):

It's allowed in normal mode (a.k.a. *sloppy mode*), but in ES5 *strict mode*, assignments to undeclared variables will throw an error, so it can be considered *deprecated* in some sense.